# Fastest way to load category and save programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, programmatically, save

I want to load all collection in Magento 2 and save one by one programmatically. is there any faster way to do so.

I tried below code for one category

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->setStoreId(0)->load(17);
$category->save();
```

Comment: you can create custom command for save category

Comment: Can you please add some context to your request?

Comment: @JonathanRibas i want to get category collection in a varaible and i want to foreach all this category just save. nothing attribute need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

> **Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="quoteGridAssignSalesrep" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Console\Command\CategorySave</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **Vendor\Module\Console\Command\CategorySave.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;

class CategorySave extends Command
{
    protected $categoryFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        AppState $appState)
    {
        $this->appState = $appState;
        $this->categoryFactory =$categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('command_name')
            ->setDescription('The description of you command here!');

        parent::configure();
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        try{
        $this->appState->setAreaCode('global');
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }
    try{
    $categoryCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection();
    foreach($categoryCollection as $category)
    {
        $category->save();
        $output->writeln('Save Category Id' . $category->getId());
    }
    }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln('Error In Category Id ' .$category->getId(). $e->getMessage());
        }
}
}
```

> **After This Run This Command**

```
php bin/magento command_name
```

Comment: i am getting [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Invalid URL key

Comment: when you get this error ??/

Comment: while running this command php bin/magento category_save

Comment: i had replaced command_name with category_save in code

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22187 issue of category save

Comment: check which category saving issue and check save that category manually

Comment: check updated code for track which category getting issue

Comment: ok thanks i am checking

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension which creates random categories via console command

This is the fastest method I could find

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Faker/blob/master/Console/Command/Category.php#L61

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Faker/blob/master/Helper/Category.php#L46-L70

Doesn't cover loading categories but if you cover loading via a category collection as the other answer suggests this should be enough.